# Refresh form when selected change interactive report oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a page with two regions, an interactive report and a form.

I have a dynamic action on the report, when I click on a row, it sets the value of an item to the id of the row.

How can I refresh the form, to get the value related to the (Id) in item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, form regions don't refresh, up to APEX 19.2 anyway. You'd probably want to use an Execute PL/SQL action to get the values for the form items. Here's a complete example.

1. Create a new blank page. My page was 26. You'll need to update the following to the page number you have.
2. Create a new region. Set **Title** to **Employees**, **Type** to **Interactive Report**, **Table Name** to **EMP**, and **Static ID** to **emps-reg**.
3. Select the **EMPNO** column of the report and set **Static ID** to **empno-col**.
4. Create another new region. Set **Title** to **Employee Details**, **Type** to **Form**, and **Table Name** to **EMP**.
5. Select the **P26_EMPNO** item (created automatically after the last step). Enable the **Primary Key** setting under **Source**.
6. Create a Dynamic Action. Set **Name** to **Employee row clicked**, **Event** to **Click**, **Selection Type** to **jQuery Selector**, jQuery Selector to `#emps-reg table:eq(1) tr:not(:eq(0))`, and **Event Scope** to **Dynamic**.

   Setting Event Scope to Dynamic will keep the Dynamic Action working after the report has been refreshed.
7. Select the Action that was created by default in the previous step. Set **Action** to **Set Value**, **Type** to **JavaScript Expression**, and **JavaScript Expression** to `$(this.triggeringElement).find('td[headers="empno-col"]').text()`.

   The JavaScript expression will start with the `tr` that was clicked and traverse down to the `td` element that has the employee's empno and return that value.
8. Right-click the **P26_EMPNO** item in the form region and select **Create Dynamic Action**. This will create a Dynamic Action with the event settings correctly configured. Set **Name** to **P26_EMPNO changed**.
9. Select the Action created by default in the previous step. Set **Action** to **Execute PL/SQL Code**, then enter the following code in PL/SQL Code:

   ```
   select ename, job, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm, deptno
   into :P26_ENAME, :P26_JOB, :P26_MGR, :P26_HIREDATE, :P26_SAL, :P26_COMM, :P26_DEPTNO
   from emp
   where empno = :P26_EMPNO;
   ```
10. In the same action, set **Page Items to Submit** to **P26_EMPNO**. This will transfer the value in the primary key item to session state prior to executing your code.
11. In the same action, set **Page Items to Return** to **P26_ENAME,P26_JOB,P26_MGR,P26_HIREDATE,P26_SAL,P26_COMM,P26_DEPTNO**. This will return the current values in session state to the items in the page.

Because you're populating the items via Ajax, you may need to add additional code for things that would normally be specified in the form item, like date or number formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Dynamic Action (DA), which triggers when the ID in the item is changed and then refreshes the form.

Create a DA. Set the "Event" of the "When" attribute of the DA to "Change", the "Selection Type" to "Item" and then select the item where you save your ID.

Set the True Action to "Refresh" and chose "Region" as "Affected Elements", then select the specific Region you want to refrseh, which is your form.

Now when the value of the ID item changes, the form will be refreshed.

Comment: I tried that but not working fine , the form not refresh

Comment: Have you set the item with the ID in the "Page Items to Submit" option of the form?